# Vanilla JavaScript - Get the value of radio buttons and display the value in the DOM

Tags: javascript, function, dom, radio-button, addeventlistener

I set up a form on the left-hand side of my page and am displaying what the user enters on the right-hand side of my page (as practice with JS).

I have a list of radio buttons with the same name.

```
<div class="subscribe">
  <p>Would you like to subscribe?</p>
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="yes">
  <label for="no">No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="no">
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of those radio buttons and display what the user selects by adding a new div to the DOM, but I can't seem to get the code right. I have been able to make this work for other types of input fields (text, number, etc.), but am really having trouble with these radio buttons.

```js
// Get Subscription Status - NEEDS MORE WORK!!!!!
let sub = getRadioVals();

function getRadioVals() {
  let val;
  let radios = document.getElementsByName("subscribe");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      val = radios[i].value;
    }
  }
  return val;
}

sub.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  // create div
  let subDiv = document.createElement("div");
  subDiv.innerText = sub.value;

  // add div to DOM
  document.querySelector(".data-container").appendChild(subDiv);

});
```

```html
<div class="subscribe">
  <p>Would you like to subscribe?</p>
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="yes">
  <label for="no">No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="no">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of radio buttons, they have mutually exclusive values. i.e. if one radio button is selected, its value is 'on' and if you de-select it, then its value is 'off' ('on' and 'off' are the defaults for every radio button).

From your question, I understand that you want these radio buttons to be mutually dependent. i.e user can either select Yes or No, not both yes and no. Therefore, I have added values to the radio buttons. If you select the radio button for 'Yes' it the value you can read in the JS will be 'Yes' and for the radio button 'No', the value you can read now will be 'No'.

In the Javascript code, I am using querySelectorAll and retrieving radios (nodelist), then using the Array.prototype.forEach( ) function in order to add eventListeners to capture the values on click Event. If you store these values in a single variable, you can just have the value be either 'Yes' or 'No' as you click on any one of them. You can try to run the code snippet, in case you have any queries, please comment below.

```js
let radioVal;

const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="subscribe"]');
radios.forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('click', function () {
    radioVal = radio.value;
    console.log(radioVal);
  });
});
```

```html
          <div class="subscribe">
            <p>Would you like to subscribe?</p>
            <label for="yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="yes" value="Yes" />
            <label for="no">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="no" value="No" />
          </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//adding an event listener to the radio buttons
$("[name='subscribe']").click(function(){
  //get the label's inner text value
  let option = $(this).prev().text()
  //appending the option chosen to an element with a data-container tag  
  $(".data-container").append(`<div>${option}</div>`)
  //changing the display text value to the option chosen instead
    $(".data-container").text(`${option}`)
})
```

This uses JQuery so I hope you don't mind. You need an event listener for `getRadioVals()` because this function will only execute once and that's on the DOMContentLoaded so it won't react to a change like an event listener.

That's all you need to do really. Looking at your code I don't know why you need a blur event. Just add a click event to the radio buttons.

Comment: I don't know jQuery yet (that's why I put "vanilla JavaScript" in the subject). I was using a blur event because that's what I used on my other input fields, but yes, I agree that a click event is better in this instance.