# How to collect choices from various radio button groups to echo specific content

Tags: php, radio-button

do you know how to collect specific choices from various radio buttons to pass to a div or to another field a specific value (in jquery, vanilla or php)?
For example...

RADIO_1

- choice-A
- choice-B
- choice-C

RADIO_2

- choice-A
- choice-B
- choice-C

If user check RADIO_1 > choice-A & RADIO_2 > choice-B than pass text "R1aR2b" to field x

If user check RADIO_1 > choice-B & RADIO_2 > choice-C than pass text "R1bR2c" to field x

...and so on

thank you

I have tryied (but doesnt work):

```
<?php
$level = $_GET["levelRadio"];
$shape = $_GET["shapeRadio"];
$state = "first choice $level, second choice $shape than:";
if ( $level == "A1" && $shape == "B1" ) {
  echo "$state A1B1";
}
if ( $level == "A2" && $shape == "B2" ) {
  echo "$state A2B2";
}
?>

<form class="choices">
  <div class="card first-card d-none d-lg-block">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="btn-link">
        Question 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset id="levels" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">
        <input type="radio" name="levelRadio" value="A1" checked> A1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">
        <input type="radio" name="levelRadio" value="A2"> A2
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <div class="btn-link">
        Question 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <fieldset id="shapes">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="shapeRadio" value="B1" checked>
          B1
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="shapeRadio" value="B2">
          B2
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="shapeRadio" value="B3">
          B3
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  <button id="btn_confirm_data" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What did you already try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? As you are open to JS as well. [Vanilla JavaScript - Get the value of radio buttons and display the value in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772025/vanilla-javascript-get-the-value-of-radio-buttons-and-display-the-value-in-the)

Comment: @Uwe 
umm no, I think this is for only one choice. I need retrieve all choices of the form and echo a result for every different configuration

Comment: you can use that linked solution to get the values for each of your Radio Buttons. Maybe start with your first Radio Button and try to display it in your field. If that works try it with the second one. 
From your example Data you don't need some complex conditional logic but print out (JavaScript):  `fieldX = "R1" + levelRadioValue + "R2" + shapeRadioValue`

Comment: What does not work in your code? Are you getting the values? In PHP you could simply echo them as well: `echo  "R1" . $level . "R2" . $shape;`

Comment: I will look for another solution and keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this only with js, but hence you tagged PHP in the question, here is maybe a good example of how to do it with PHP...
The example is with one radio button, but still, the logic is the same.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 1">Radio 1
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 2">Radio 2
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 3">Radio 3
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['radio'])) {
      echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
  }
?>
```

The example is rough, just to give you some insights.
Note - next time give code example, instead of explanations, it would be easier for others to help you.

Comment: hi Yavor, this solution is for a single choiche I need to concatenate choices of all form radios.

(thank you for advice on give code example :)

Comment: @ArDiEm
use the example to add another radio buttons group and see it present in the $_POST when the form is submitted.